# How to delay 2 seconds in PHP to include?

Tags: php, sleep

I want this PHP script to wait 2 sec before including an sp.php (server panel).
The `sleep(2);` doesn´t work for me (It doesn´t do anything at all.)

My code:

```
<?php
$cookie_name = "sc";
?>
<?php
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
    include 'noserver.php';
} else {
    echo "Server found";
    sleep(2);
    include 'sp.php';
}
?>
```

Any ideas? It`s for the server hosting web.

Comment: Sleep before including feels all kinds of wrong... can you describe what it is that you're trying to achieve? Maybe we can suggest a proper way to do it.

Comment: Hi,
I try that when the user visits the page cns.php (The page to which I try to add sleep ();), it first detects if the cookie "sc" (Server created) has been set, and if not, loads the content from the file "noserver. php ", but if so, it will type" Server found ", wait 2 seconds (which is important) and load the server panel (sp.php).

I hope I described it well this time.

Comment: For future reference: when you say things like _"wait 2 seconds (which is important)"_, it's, well... _important_ that you explain why this is crucial to your app. Are you waiting for a response? Something else to become available? It's information like this that can truly help the community suggest the right solution for you. If you say something about the thing in your question is important to you, then it's likely it's also important to those trying to answer said question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Javascript with `setTimeout` and `window.location.href` to redirect to the file.

Example:

```
<?php

if (!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
    include 'noserver.php';
} else {
    echo 'Server found';
    echo '<script>setTimeout(function(){window.location.href = 
    "http://yourwebsite.com/sp.php"}, 2 * 1000);</script>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Oh, thanks so much!
This works, but it just redirects to the page.
I wanted to keep the url as it is, but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You probably **think** it is doing nothing at all because *you don't see the output until the include has been completed*. Try putting a `flush` command and flushing any buffering after writing "Server found":

```
print "Server found\n";
// in the very worst case you might be forced to send "<!-- GARBAGE -->" 
// with enough "garbage" to force any intermediate buffers to flush.
if (ob_get_level()) {
    ob_flush();
}
flush();
...
```

However, as it has been suggested, this is likely a XY problem. You want something *else* to happen, and a server side delay of 2 seconds is probably not the best way to achieve this.

For example, if you want a quick "Server found" message to immediately appear, and then a slower page to load (**even if it is the same page**), you could do this with a session flag or using jQuery and a DOM load.

In the first case you load the same page twice, the first time showing the message, setting the flag and reloading using Location or a Meta reload (`echo "<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2" />`)). The second time, with the flag set, you un-set the flag and run the `include()`. Problem solved with no server `sleep()` overhead.